# Copy "Name" from Sheet 1 if "User_ID" On Sheet 2 Matches "User_ID" on Sheet 1

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to copy data from a cell on Sheet 1 to a cell on Sheet 2 if my "User_ID" columns match on both sheets.

i.e.

```
SHEET 1
User_ID    Name    Email
1          Jon     Jon@Gmail
```

=

```
SHEET 2
User_ID               Name                         Email
1            (Data from Sheet1 B:3)       (Data from Sheet1 C:3)
```

I've tried using `VLOOKUP`, `Arrayformula`, `INDEX`, and `MATCH`, but I'm getting nowhere. In Python, I'd use a simple `IF` statement, but I can't seem to make those work here.

Does anyone know the magic formula to make this work?

Comment: What formulas did you try? `=VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$C$10,2)` should work for the name, and change the `,2)` to `,3)` for the email.

Answer (score 1):

paste in **B2** cell of **SHEET 2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 'SHEET 1'!A2:C, {2, 3}, 0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving it with: `=iferror(index(Master!B:B,match(A4,Master!$A:$A,0)),"")`